# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacia\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php on line 1125

Tags: php, sendmail

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacia\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php on line 1125

how to fix it

```
<?php
   $nome="myname";
   $apelido="mylastname";
   $email="myemail0@gmail.com";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'myemail0@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'myemail0';
$mail->setFrom('myemail0@gmail.com', 'myname');
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $nome. ' ' .$apelido);
$mail->addAddress($email, $nome. ' ' .$apelido);
$mail->Subject = 'SendMail';
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('message.html'), __DIR__);
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain text message body';
//$mail->addAttachment('test.txt');
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may modify the php.ini at runtime with *ini_set*

```
//300 seconds = 5 minutes  
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`.

I don't know exact numbers but I believe SMTP servers can take up to few minutes to respond. 30 seconds isn't nearly enough.